# How to give the library background as Aldiko Android App to Grid View in android?

Tags: android

I have to give library background for our gridview in our Android App. Because I am making an App just like a library. How to achieve the same? Please suggest me regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

For providing library background for the gridview, create the backgroud image as you want and set as as the background for the gridview.

you can set background in xml file as well as in code

for xml file add attribute in the GridView tag as( suppose your image file name is mybackground)

```
<GridView android:backgorund="@drawable/mybackground" />
```

for the code

```
GridView gv=(GridView)findViewById(R.drawable.myGridView);
gv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybackground)
```